# 301 permenanat redirect in opencart

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, opencart

I have to use 301 permenant redirect in my opencart site. Am using the following codes in my .htaccess. Both are working in the case of http:// but not in https://

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

and

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^meinedomain.de 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.meinedomain.de/$1 [r=301,L] 

RewriteCond %{HTTPS_HOST} ^meinedomain.de 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://ssl.meinedomain.de/$1 [r=301,L]
```

But some of my pages are loding in https:// like sign in, checkout etc. When i use the above code then am not able to sign in to the site. What changes are needed for the proper working of https...??

When I search my site in google then www. does not appear in the result. It shows mysite.com. What can I do for this??
Anybody please help.
Thanks.

Comment: Configure your SSL settings in OC - for cookie and domain cross policy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing called `%{HTTPS_HOST}`, try this (and don't forget to escape dots in regex) :

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^meinedomain\.de$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.meinedomain.de/$1 [r=301,L] 

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^meinedomain\.de$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://ssl.meinedomain.de/$1 [r=301,L]
```

Comment: what do you mean by couldn't sign in ? what did you try ? what happened ? what error did you get ?

Comment: If you can't sign in, make sure that the HTTPS url in the `/admin/config.php` is exactly the same as the HTTPS URL you have above, and that there are no redirects affecting those